# Parse, PFCloud - how to rewrite this PFQuery?

Tags: ios, parse-platform, pfquery

I've been stuck on this for a full day so would be great if anyone could point me in the right direction!

I'm currently building an IOS app that uses Parse as back-end and Parse Cloud to encrypt/decrypt data. In the following code I perform a PFQuery on Parse to get the data that I need however I want to decrypt the data on server-side before returning the data.

This is the code I use now to request and show the data:

```
(PFQuery *)queryForTable
{
    arrdossier=[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults ]objectForKey:@"Dossier_IDs"];
    query1  = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:self.parseClassName];
    [query1 whereKey:@"Dossier_ID" containedIn:arrdossier];
    [query1 whereKey:@"status" equalTo:@"open"];

  return query1;
}
```

The code that I have on Parse Cloud is:

```
Parse.Cloud.define("decryptQuery", function(request, response) {

    var doss = Parse.Object.extend("Dossier");
    var q = new Parse.Query(doss);
    q.containsAll("Dossier_ID", request.params.Dossier_IDs);
    q.find({
        success: function(results) {
        // iterate through results to call decrypt()
        response.success();
    }, 
    error: function() {
        response.error("failed");
    }
    })
});
```

What would the PFCloud callFunctionInBackground look like to achieve this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I only have the objective C code that I use, But it shouldn't be hard to translate this to Swift.

```
[PFCloud callFunctionInBackground:@"decryptQuery"
                       withParameters:@{@"Dossier_IDs": @[ARRAY WITH IDS]}
                                block:^(id answer, NSError *error) {
                                    if (!error) {
                                        //do something with answer
                                    }
                                    else {
                                        //do something with error
                                    }

}];
```

Comment: queryForTable is expecting a PFQuery. I have changed the values for "results" in the Cloud Code however how can I return this? And how can I turn this into a PFQuery?

Comment: @maverickandy to call a cloud function you don't need a PFQuery, call the function as I provided above, Do you need to pass any info to the cloud? if so what exactly? and what do you want the cloud to return?

Comment: The flow is as follows: In the IOS app I run PFQuery to pull the data (i.e. the "Dossiers"). However I've now added functionality to encrypt/decrypt the data using Cloud code. As such my IOS function (queryForTable) needs to return a PFQuery for my IOS app to function correctly.

So now I've built a Cloud code to run the PFQuery and iterate through the results of the PFQuery and update the fields with the decrypted versions (e.g. results[i].set("name", decrypt(name)).

Is there a way for me to return a PFQuery (or PFObject and somehow cast it to PFQuery) from the Cloud code?

Comment: So to add: your function is very helpful and has helped me to the next step however I now have the problem above.

Comment: @maverickandy I don't know of any way of converting it to a PFQuery, however you can return the results from your cloud code, and then use that array to do whatever you were doing with that PFQuery, if you should me what you were doing maybe I can help.

Comment: Thanks Eli. I've created 2 paste bins. 1: http://pastebin.com/vxED5xXJ this pastebin shows my cloud code. I use a Parse.Query to grab 2 objects by specifiying the 2 Dossier_IDs. On line 27/28 I assign the new decrypted values. I want to return "results" to the IOS app (2nd pastebin) but this does not seem to work.

http://pastebin.com/eukRN9hd shows the IOS code. On line 9 I pass all the IDs - this works fine so thanks for code(!). However the *resultsQuery is always nil. I can't seem to pass the "results" values back to this function. DO you know how to solve this?